# Unable to run Chrome webdriver in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying selenium for the first time and I get a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'` error, when running code taken from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-selenium-to-web-scrape-with-example-80f9b23a843a):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = '/Users/krishpatil/Downloads/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get('https://hoopshype.com/salaries/players/')
```

I have tried updating Selenium and downloading the right chromedriver, however the problem still persists.

Answer (score 16):

1. Download the chromedriver from [Here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
2. Unzip the downloaded file
3. Move the file 'chromedriver.exe' to the folder of project, and remove its path from the code, the code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: This answer is a Winner. Fixed no problems.

Comment: worked perfectly. but why this is happened?

Comment: @wisnshaftler, it could be with the accessing a file outside the project. Having it in a project folder maybe will have different access controls.

Comment: Not a good solution, I followed the steps, but still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm running the code in visual studio code(ubuntu server) from mac laptop.,